# Does this Relational Database Model make sense?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Here is a flat version of my datamodel. It is sensor readings for various data acquisition equipment.

[image: 0]

https://i1295.photobucket.com/albums/b628/colnewman26/Work%20Screen%20Shots/RobinDataModel_zpsdfc40151.png~original

Here is my Relational Database model. Does this make sense.

[image: 1]

https://i1295.photobucket.com/albums/b628/colnewman26/RobinDataModel_zps847d94b5.png~original

If not what you suggest?

Comment: Looks good to me.  But it really depends on how well it maps to your requirements matrix.

Comment: as per @RobertHarvey, what are you going to do with the data in the relational model? If you're usually/only going to reconstruct/manipulate the measurements table from the first image, then a table of events with a lot of fields would suffice. If you're going to be doing time-series analysis on discrete event/measurement types, you might want to consider a simpler representation of quantities and measurements (e.g. see Analysis Patterns, by Martin Fowler)

Comment: Well it's mostly just used for graphing for reports, and finding highs and lows etc. Each test instance will have a different number of channels for each type of sensor, and I also need to ability to add new types of tests in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you may have over normalized this based on the original table design.  Unless you are certain that you will need an indeterminate number of factors, you pay a pretty high penalty in insertion and retrieval of data with that schema.  Having worked with high data volume sensors (GPS readings) I found that performance considerations pay a heavy role as you start viewing trending data as the data volume grows.